# XSL Replace() function strips out markup

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I’m trying to escape the quotes that come from user input in a html document but the replace() function is removing the markup when I use it. Why?

I.e From the XSL bellow code, If I change this line from :

```
<xsl:copy-of select="replace($s, '&quot;', '\\&quot;')" />
```

to

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$s" />
```

It works but obviously without doing the quote escaping which I need. Or do you have any other method to escape the quote.

PS: I need the escaping because I am passing the value to a backend variable with c#, and if I don’t escape it the code brakes.

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">
<xsl:template name="encode-string">
  <xsl:param name="s" select="@* | node()"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="replace($s, '&quot;', '\\&quot;')" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="encode-string">
    <xsl:with-param name="s" >
      <xsl:copy-of select="Contact/node()"/>
    </xsl:with-param> 
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

HTML

```
<Contact> 
<MobileNumber>0123456789</MobileNumber>
<Email type="new">johndoe@coldmail.com</Email>
<Address type="red">Antartica"s drive 41</Address>
</Contact>
```

I need to escape all of the node's content. That is, everything within  needs to be treated as one single string. Something like serialize, but it should include the child nodes attributes also. (everything)

Result wanted:

`<MobileNumber>0123456789</MobileNumber><Email type=\"new\">johndoe@coldmail.com</Email> <Address type=\"red\">Antartica\"s drive 41</Address>`

So that I can pass it to a C# Variable like this:

`string content = "<MobileNumber>0123456789</MobileNumber><Email type=\"new\">johndoe@coldmail.com</Email> <Address type=\"red\">Antartica\"s drive 41</Address>";`

Comment: You might need to explain in more detail how your complete input looks and which parts you need to transform in which way, what output format (XML, HTML, plain text) you want. In what way does your backend break if a quote inside XML is not escaped?

Comment: I need to escape all of the node's content. That is, everything within <Contact> needs to be treated as one single string. Something like serialize, but it should include the child nodes attributes also. (everything)

Comment: (Added more details in question). Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to construct C# source code or why do you need that double quote escaping? If the XSLT with Saxon returns a string with the XML to your C# code I don't see why you would need the escaping, unless you really construct C# source code. I am currently not sure whether it is simply a problem of using the right Saxon API or whether it is an XSLT problem (which could be solved by calling `replace` on the `serialize` result, see http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcot).

Comment: Thanks Martin, exactly what I needed and best thing is a one liner.

Answer (score 0):

The [`replace()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) function takes a string as input and also returns a string, so it's not going to do what you're intending.

If you want to replace the character globally, consider using a [character-map](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#character-maps)...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" use-character-maps="encode"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:character-map name="encode">
    <xsl:output-character character="&quot;" string="&amp;quot;"/>
  </xsl:character-map>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Full working example: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMen

Comment: I like this approach but the problem is that the XSL file where I have this is shared with other transformation which I don't want the map to apply. Also I need to escape the attributes, in the example: `type="new"` and  `type="red"`

Answer (score 0):

XSLT does not operate on a lexical string containing markup, it operates on a tree of nodes. So your statement that the replace() function removes the markup suggests you haven't really got the right conceptual model of how XSLT works. Unless you fix that, you're going to have a lot more problems like this.

If you supply a node as input to a function like replace() that expects a string, then the processor extracts the string value of the node, which is the concatenation of all the text node descendants of the node. You can view that as "removing the markup" if you like, but it's not really an accurate description.

The best way of tackling this problem is by applying the replace function to each descendant text node separately. In XSLT 3.0 you could do this as:

```
<xsl:mode name="escape-quotes" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<xsl:template match="text()" mode="escape-quotes">
  <xsl:value-of select="replace(.....)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and then replace your `xsl:copy-of` with `xsl:apply-templates` with `mode="escape-quotes"`. In earlier XSLT versions you'll need to spell out the "shallow-copy" template rule in full.

Comment: I need to escape all of the node's content. That is everything within <Contact> needs to be treated as one single string. I think that way the replace() will do the job then, right?

Comment: Something like serialize, but it should include the child nodes attributes also.

Comment: See added details in the question. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

@Martin Honnen has provided exactly what I needed in the question's comment with this link to the solution http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcot
By simply using serilize before the replace call:

```
  <xsl:template match="Contact">
       <xsl:value-of select="replace(serialize(*), '&quot;', '\\&quot;')"/>
  </xsl:template>
```